# Flask application deployed through IIS is not allowing API requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, iis

I have a web flask application I have deployed using Windows IIS.

I am able to access the website and it shows up but when I click on the "start button" I have built within the website, which causes a series of API calls using the requests library. I am seeing that the data is not being "GET" or "PUT".

When I run the code using Visual Studio Code I am seeing the data being populated but once it is deployed using IIS the data is not being populated which leads me to believe it could possibly be some type of security measure within the IIS.

I have thought that the reason may be because it is just a http website currently and the browser is not allowing API requests but I have also tried to make the website https using this article (https://www.educba.com/flask-https/) explaining the adhoc ssl context method
I am able to access the deployment URL and my application shows up but the functionality of the API is still not working so I am thinking that the HTTP and HTTPS is not the root cause.

Here is my app.py currently

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/active", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def active():
    try:
        
        
        import json
        import requests
        import pandas as pd

    

        EXUser = 'API'
        EXPw = 'test'
        EXI = 'Example'
        url = requests.get(
            f'https://{EXI}.api.com/api/values/0153ecf7-9e90-4aef-ad0b-ed8d0aa7092f', auth=(EXUser,EXPw ))

        myToken = 'exampletoken'
        myUrl = 'https://api2.com/api/v1/devices.json'
        head = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Token Example',
            'Cookie': 'XSRF-TOKEN=Example'
        }
        sfresp = requests.get(myUrl, headers=head)

        r = json.loads(url.content)
        sr = json.loads(sfresp.content)
        df = pd.json_normalize(sr, 'devices')
        df1 = pd.json_normalize(r, record_path='userDefinedValues')
        df1.set_index('userDefinedKeyId', inplace=True)
        owner = df1['value']['66ea21fb-036f-4081-ac58-6b4c9e3caa54']
        lon = df['device.location.lng'][0].astype(str)
        bat = df['device.battery_status'][0].astype(str)
        lat = df['device.location.lat'][0].astype(str)
        did = df['device.id'][0].astype(str)
        payload = 'properties=[       {           "name": "Owner",            "value": "' + owner + '"      }  ]'
        myUrl2 = f'https://api2.com/api/v1/devices/{did}/custom_properties.json'
        test = requests.put(myUrl2, headers=head, data=payload)
        payload2 = {'userDefinedValues': [{'userDefinedKeyId': 'ec94503d-efb4-4b04-82ac-1717beff85b9',
                                        'userDefinedKeyName': 'Latitude',
                                        'value': lat},
                                        {'userDefinedKeyId': 'a64d94c5-e156-4f2d-b218-82597bfa95ce',
                                        'userDefinedKeyName': 'Longitude',
                                        'value': lon},
                                        {'userDefinedKeyId': '537b843a-044e-45c0-9625-93c4f52c539d',
                                        'userDefinedKeyName': 'Battery Level',
                                        'value': bat}]}
        test1 = requests.patch(f'https://{EXI}.api.com/api/assets/0153ecf7-9e90-4aef-ad0b-ed8d0aa7092f', auth=(
            EXUser, AVIPw), data=json.dumps(payload2))
        return render_template('index.html')

    except:
        return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')
```

index.html code of the single start button that renders on the page

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Data Integration Demo</title>

</head>

<body>
    <form action="/active" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Start">
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Just to reiterate the app is deployed using IIS, I have followed the steps here (https://medium.com/@dpralay07/deploy-a-python-flask-application-in-iis-server-and-run-on-machine-ip-address-ddb81df8edf3). I am able to browse to the application using localhost but the part of the script is not running that PUTs and GETs data. The code works when I run it using Visual Studio Code but once it has been deployed it no longer does the API requests process within the code. I tried to replace values into example values so I may have missed some sections in the code, I can assure that it does work.

Comment: While you must have read a lot about IIS, you should get started from IIS log files and the status/substatus codes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code Once you know the codes, FRT can lead you further https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Merely claiming "not allowing API requests" indicates that you are far away from the cause.

Comment: Thanks, I  have checked out these logs, They are returning 200 when It navigates to the /active. I am still not seeing the information exchanged through the API @LexLi

Comment: Have you received an error exception in Python when deploying on IIS?

Comment: @JennyDai I have not received any python exception errors, which is really strange, the application is deployed through the IIS and everything is functioning except the portion of code that picks up the 2 APIS. I can say that I deployed it on a different folder on the C drive that is not "C:\inetpub"